# Install Laravel with Composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install Laravel on my computer with Composer.
So I did install Composer well.

And now I run the command line:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel demo --prefer-dist
```

But i always have this error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The
>   "http://packagist.org/p/laravel/laravel$43a87aca57a4c34246b77034dd42057
>   3201ad96143b5c65bb87611e6d808d872.json" file could not be downloaded:
>   send   of 103 bytes failed with errno=10053 Une connexion ?tablie a
>   ?t? abandonn?e    par un logiciel de votre ordinateur h?te.   send of
>   21 bytes failed with errno=10053 Une connexion ?tablie a ?t? abando
>   nn?e par un logiciel de votre ordinateur h?te.   send of 114 bytes
>   failed with errno=10053 Une connexion ?tablie a ?t? aband   onn?e par
>   un logiciel de votre ordinateur h?te.   send of 2 bytes failed with
>   errno=10053 Une connexion ?tablie a ?t? abandon   n?e par un logiciel
>   de votre ordinateur h?te.   send of 2 bytes failed with errno=10053
>   Une connexion ?tablie a ?t? abandon   n?e par un logiciel de votre
>   ordinateur h?te.   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
>
> install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev]
>   [--no-dev] [--no-p lugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts]
>   [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--ver bose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
>   [packages1] ... [packagesN]

I googled it, but didn't find an answer.
I'm at home and don't have proxy who stop me.

Do you have an idea why I have this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe the remote service is having problems?

Comment: The error message definitely points to an issue downloading the Laravel package info from Packagist. Though you should try updating your composer installation just in case it's out of date and using old URLs or something - `composer self-update`.

Comment: I copied your composer command exactly and it worked for me. Try a self update like alexrussell says and see if that fixes it.

Comment: There's now an easier way to install Laravel. Try running... composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1" - And then us laravel new demo

Comment: I tried to update composer. Here the message: You are already using composer version 1e27ff5e22df81e3cd0cd36e5fdd4a3c5a031f4a. Apparently I already have the last version of composer. I also tried running composer global require, but still have the same error message. I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you're running a web filter, especially *K9 Web Protection*, uninstall that first and retry. If the problem persists, read ahead:

The problem is that Composer downgrades to *http* requests after the first *https* request to the server. This is done to improve performance/speed and to ensure file integrity/security via the sha256 hashes. In any case, this will cause a 10053 error (errno=10053 An established connection was aborted
 by the software in your host machine ... failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!) on some machines.

The reason this happens to some people and not others seems to be the manner in which your ISP handles *http* requests. In my case, they're re-routed through a caching proxy; which doesn't work well with the way Composer crafts its *http* requests. That's what happened with me - others may have a different cause. In any case, the fix is to force Composer to use *https* requests instead of *http* requests:

Add the following to your Composer installation's config file (composer.json). In Windows, you may find this file at C:\Users{Your Username}\AppData\Roaming\Composer.

```
"repositories": [
{
    "packagist": false
},
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://packagist.org/"
}
],
```

Then go ahead and create your project again with the same command: composer create-project laravel/laravel demo --prefer-dist. It should work now.

Comment: Smart! BTW How did you understand what's happening in the ISP?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall the web filter, changing the composer.json file (above) in order to use HTTPS was enough for me.